# What is a reason of having ResBody generic type inside Request interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

The `index.d.ts` file of the `express` lib has the next interface

```
interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

What is a reason to pass `ResBody` generic type to the `Request` interface?

As far I understand this should be assigned to the `req` object of middleware

```
  expressMiddleware(
    req: Request<{}, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery>,
    res: Response<ResBody>,
    next: NextFunction,
  ) {}
```

But `Response` type has own generic for this case.

Could you please clarify me this question?

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I was wondering myself

Comment: @AmitLevy no, I didn't manage to figure it out. As far as I remember, I treated it like "weird flex, but ok"